# Find the sum of maximum and minimum value of $f(x)=\sin^2x+8\cos x-7$

Tags: trigonometry

The above expression can be written as 
$$f(x)=-\cos^2x+8\cos x-6$$
$$=-[(\cos x-4)^2-10]$$
$$=10-(\cos x-4)^2$$
So the minimum value would be when cos x is most negative ie. -1
The minimum value would be -15 and the max value of would be 1

The minimum value given in the answer is -6? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just by plotting the given function ($f(x) = \sin^2{x} + 8\cos{x}-7$) you can see that it does have a minimum of $-15$ and a maximum of $1$. So maybe the problem definition is false or incomplete ....

Comment: Is the value in answer the minimum or the sum of minimum and maximum?

Comment: You did everything correctly.  The given answer is wrong.  Textbooks or whatever resources you use are not necessarily correct.

Comment: Probably there might be the constraint that $\cos x \geq 0$

Comment: Unless there are more restrictions (like an interval for a domain), [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5bdexxtcg1) agrees with you.

Comment: @AndrewChin no such restrictions are provided

Comment: @WETutorialSchool that’s what I thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right!!!

[image]

Minimum will be when cos X is minimum and maximum will be when cos X is maximum

Comment: Just to let you know, I've taken the liberty to swap out the picture for one with a better aspect ratio for more convenient viewing.

Comment: Thanks for changing the picture  :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note to OP:** Your argument for min is right. For max write $$(10-f(x))=(\cos x-4)^2 \ge 9, ~when~ x=0, 2\pi \implies f(x) \le 1 ~(max) $$

**Calculus solution:**

$$f(x)=\sin^2 x+8 \cos x-7 \implies f'(x)=2\sin x \cos x-8 \sin x-0 \implies 2\sin x (\cos x-4)=0 \implies \sin x=0 \implies x=0, \pi, 2\pi ~in ~ x\in [0,2\pi].$$
Next $$f''(x)=2\cos (2x)-8\cos x \implies f''(0)=-5 <0 ~(max)~, f''(\pi)=6 ~(min)~, f''(2\pi)=-6 ~(max).$$
Finally $$f_{max}=f(0)=f(2\pi)=1, f_{min}=f(\pi)=-15.$$

Comment: The OP already has an elementary solution without calculus. They are asking for confirmation whether or not their answer is correct.

Comment: $YiFan Thanks, I have edited it.